# Convert json structure and conditional update values using environment variables with JQ

Tags: json, jq

I have the following json:

```json
{
  "Parameters": {
    "AmiId": "/my/image/id/latest",
    "InstanceType": "t3.medium",
    "Environment": "$ENV_DEFINITION"
  }
}
```

And I have exported the `$ENV_DEFINITION` with the value `dev`.

NOTE: I want to keep the literal value `$ENV_DEFINTION` if the environment variable is not set. That's why I'm using the `// .` part when accessing the `env[]` array in the command below.

I need to obtain the following output:

```bash
'AmiId=/my/image/id/latest' 'InstanceType=t3.medium' 'Environment=dev'
```

I'm able to get the above output witht he following `jq` command:

```bash
jq -r '[ .Parameters | to_entries[] | .value |= (env[.[1:]] // .) | [.key, .value] | join("=") ] | @sh' < myfile.json
```

But then I needed to add a few more parameters to json:

```json
{
  "Parameters": {
    "AmiId": "/my/image/id/latest",
    "InstanceType": "t3.medium",
    "Environment": "$ENV_DEFINITION",
    "MinSize": 0,
    "MaxSize": 0,
    "DesiredCapacity": 0,
  }
}
```

And `jq` started to fail with the following message:

```bash
jq: error (at myfile:10): Cannot index number with object
```

Well, looks like it fails when the json values are integer as it cannont index integer values at the following place: `env[.[1:]]`.

Then I came up with this new `jq` command:

```bash
jq -r '[ .Parameters | to_entries[] | select((.value|tostring)|startswith("$")) |= (env[.[1:]] // .) | [.key, .value] | join("=") ] | @sh' < myfile.json
```

But now, this fail when trying to replace the `$ENV_DEFINITION`. If I take it out of the json file, the above command works.

The error message is:

```bash
jq: error (at myfile.json:5): Cannot index object with object
```

I have tried the following

```bash
jq -r '[ .Parameters | to_entries[] | .value |= if ((.value|tostring)|startswith("$")) then (env[.[1:]] // .) else . end | [.key, .value] | join("=") ]' < myfile.json
```

But:

```bash
jq: error (at myfile.json:5): Cannot index string with string "value"
```

I'm still fighting with `jq` and it's documentation here to figure out what to do but any help will be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To only trigger the lookup if the value is a string, you can use `select(type == "string")`, which also has the `strings` shortcut. So, in your first attempt, just replace `.[1:]` with `strings[1:]`, and you should be good to go.

```bash
jq -r '[ .Parameters | to_entries[] | .value |= (env[strings[1:]] // .) | [.key, .value] | join("=") ] | @sh' < myfile.json
```